# IIS 7.5 adds no-cache to cache-control response

Tags: azure, iis-7.5, cache-control

I'm using Azure and IIS 7.5 to serve my web app, I'm not using .NET though.

I'm trying to override the default cache-control value for my static files but it seems that IIS 7.5 adds *no-cache* no matter what I specify.

My *approot/web.config* file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    ...

    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlCustom="public" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="30.00:00:00" /> 
    </staticContent>
    ...

  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

and my response headers are:

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:no-cache,public,max-age=2592000
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:4309
Content-Type:application/x-javascript
Date:Mon, 10 Sep 2012 14:42:07 GMT
ETag:"8ccd2f95a8fcd1:0"
Last-Modified:Mon, 10 Sep 2012 13:48:36 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

I do have an extra *web.config* file in one of the subfolders but that doesn't override any *clientCache* values.

Does anyone know why IIS is prepending *no-cache*?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the output cache needs a location attribute otherwise it will override the *staticContent/clientCache* setting.

```
<system.webServer>
    ...
    <caching>
        <profiles>
            <add extension="*" policy="CacheForTimePeriod" duration="00:01:00" varyByQueryString="*" varyByHeaders="X-Requested-With" location="Any" />
        </profiles>
    </caching>
    ...
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Works only in ManagedPipelIneMode : **Classic** and fails in **Integrated** Mode of application pool used in the asp.net application

Answer (score 0):

Based on your problem I think you are using Windows Azure Cloud Services with a web role.

In that case you need to use Startup task to setup Cache-Control in the IIS which will stay with your website configuration once the role is started. The Command in your Startup task should be as below per your above setting:

```
appcmd.exe set config "Default Web Site/folder" -section:system.webServer/staticContent -clientCache.cacheControlCustom:public
appcmd.exe set config "Default Web Site/folder" -section:system.webServer/staticContent -clientCache.cacheControlMode:UseMaxAge
appcmd.exe set config "Default Web Site/folder" -section:system.webServer/staticContent -clientCache.cacheControlMaxAge:"30.00:00:00"
```

If you want to know how to use appcmd in a startup task you can read [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/05/28/how-to-perform-custom-iis-configuration-such-as-adding-dynamic-compression-for-additional-mime-types-in-web-role-using-startup-task.aspx) article.